# Vue import fails when importing 'marker-animate-unobtrusive'

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

I'm working on a small vue project and I'm using [marker-animate-unobtrusive](https://github.com/terikon/marker-animate-unobtrusive) library to move markers over the map. The issue here is that when I import this library in one of my pages, the whole app won't load. for example, when I start my dev server without importing the library it starts at "localhost:port/#/login", but when I import it, it starts at "localhost:port" and only shows an empty screen.

I've tried using

```
var SlidingMarker = require('marker-animate-unobtrusive');
```

Instead of

```
import SlidingMarker from 'marker-animate-unobtrusive'
```

but it doesn't fix my issue.

edit:

SC from browser console
[image]

Comment: Please, post an error message from browser console.

Comment: @aBiscuit added a screenshot

Comment: Apparently, this library required `google` to be available on `window` object upon initialization, but it is not there yet. It is possible, that library is imported (included) in your project before `google-maps` script. Try changing the order of imports. There is not information about your project structure, so it is not possible to give a more definitive answer.

Comment: @aBiscuit thanks! that was it, i added the library using 'require' after the google-maps script was loaded. can you post your answer so i can mark it as the solution?

Comment: Done. Thanks :)

Comment: @Avrgebro did you get this to work in Vue? I am dealing with the same issue

Comment: @Jason hey yeah I managed to solve it, you have to declare the sliding marker as a global variable, and then in your initmap method, assign it with require. Make sure to assign it as the last line in your initmap method

Comment: @Avrgebro thanks for responding. before I go down this path I am curious if this plugin works with vue-google-maps. Did you use it with this by any chance?

Comment: @Jason, no i didn't i used the google maps library directly. i think it should work the same since this slidingmarker kind of inherits from google marker, so you should have no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this library requires `google` to be available on `window` object upon initialization, but it is not there yet.  It is possible, that library is imported (included) in your project before `google-maps` script.
Try changing the order of imports. Make sure that `marker-animate-unobtrusive` is loaded after `google-maps` script.