# initializing 'marker-animate-unobtrusive' in Vue fails

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

I am trying to use marker-animate-unobtrusive but I keep getting this error:

[image]

I found another post on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036075/vue-import-fails-when-importing-marker-animate-unobtrusive) that talked about requiring the file after google has loaded but I do not know how to do that. in my component I have this:

```
import SlidingMarker from 'marker-animate-unobtrusive'
```

In my mounted method I have this:

```
SlidingMarker.initializeGlobally()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected error since `SlidingMarker` extends [`google.maps.Marker` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker), GoogleMaps JavaScript API library needs to be loaded first, one option would to add a reference via `index.html` file:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=--KEY-GOES-HERE--"></script>
```

Another option would to utilize *async* JavaScript loader, e.g. [`scriptjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptjs). The example for loading GoogleMaps JavaScript API and `marker-animate-unobtrusive` module could look like this:

```
created: function(){
  get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=", () => {

    const SlidingMarker = require('marker-animate-unobtrusive')
    SlidingMarker.initializeGlobally()

    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), this.mapOptions);

    const marker = new SlidingMarker({
        position: this.mapOptions.center,
        map: map,
        title: 'Im sliding marker'
    });
 });
```

}

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/0853n1Lp/) for your reference

**Update**

With [`vue-google-maps` library](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps)  `marker-animate-unobtrusive` plugin could be integrated like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <GmapMap :center="center" :zoom="zoom" ref="mapRef"></GmapMap>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

/* global google */

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 12,
      center: { lat: 51.5287718, lng: -0.2416804 },
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
     this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then(() => {
        this.initSlidingMarker(this.$refs.mapRef.$mapObject)
    })
  },
  methods: {
    initSlidingMarker(map){
       const SlidingMarker = require('marker-animate-unobtrusive')
       SlidingMarker.initializeGlobally()


       const marker = new SlidingMarker({
            position: map.getCenter(),
            map: map,
            title: 'Im sliding marker'
       });

       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', (event) => {
          marker.setDuration(1000);
          marker.setEasing('linear');
          marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
       });
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.vue-map-container {
  height: 640px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I am trying to incorporate it with https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps and suggestions?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jason, the answer has been updated which demonstrates how to integrate vue-google-maps library  with marker-animate-unobtrusive plugin

Comment: this is awesome. I apologize but I have one more ask. Can I ping you outside of this thread?

Comment: just sent you an email. than you

Answer (score 0):

Install the package [google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google) from npm this should fix it.

Comment: I don't believe I need that. I already have google maps installed

Comment: Check your stack trace and see exactly what file the undefined error is coming from